# My Lightshot stops working recently (Windows 11, DELL)

Tags: windows, screenshot

My Lightshot stops working recently (Windows 11, DELL). I uninstalled it and installed it again with Admin rights. I can see its process but there is no icon in systray and prtscr doesn't work either. I stop the process and run it with Admin rights - no luck. Restarted my laptop also... Windows and DEL drivers are up-to-date... Any ideas are very much appreciated :)
(Snipping tool is switched off already)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I found the same issue on SuperUser, but still no solution: https://superuser.com/questions/1780524/lightshot-on-windows-11-is-hard-to-install-troubleshoot
It works on my Lenovo laptop, but not on my Dell laptop, so maybe it is a DELL issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by updating my Windows 11, including the optional updates which were about OS and Framework 3.5.
So, I uninstalled Lightshot
installed all updates
ran Lightshot setup with Admin permissions
also, I installed all my firmware updates for DELL but I'm not sure it has something to do with the fix

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved by updating Intel's drivers via this tool. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/intel-driver-support-assistant.html